# Hydrostatic force on one side of a gate of a trapezoid irrigation canal?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

A gate in an irrigation canal is constructed in the form of a trapezoid 2 m wide at the bottom, 32 m wide at the top, and 2 m high. It is placed vertically in the canal so that the water just covers the gate. Find the hydrostatic force on one side of the gate.


I know that you have to find an expression for the definite integral from 0 to 2 with the gravitational constant, the constant 1000, and the expression for the change in area. I'm not sure how to find an expression for the change in area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The expression for the change in area**

Impose a coordinate system consisting of an $h$-axis that is orthogonal to the top of the trapezoidal gate. The top of the gate is at $h = 0$ and the bottom is at $h=32$. Assume the trapezoid is an isosceles trapezoid (both of the non-parallel sides are equal in length), and that the $h$-axis coincides with its axis of symmetry. You will eventually integrate along the $h$-axis to find total force, so we are interested in finding an expression for the area of a thin strip of the trapezoid cut orthogonal to the $h$-axis. The width of this strip is $dh$, and the height is the distance between the two non-parallel sides of the trapezoid (which is a linear function $h$). Let's now find that linear function. The width is 32 at the top, and 2 at the bottom, and the height is 2, so the slope of this linear function is $\frac{2-32}{2} = -15$. At a height of 0, the width is 32, so the constant term of this linear function is 32. So, for a height $h$, the area of the thin strip of the trapezoid is given by

$$ (-15h+32) dh$$

This term multiplied by the expression for pressure at a depth $h$ is the complete integrand for your definite integral:

$$ \int_0^2 \rho g h \left( -15h+32 \right) dh$$

Comment: Thank you! For your expression (2-32)/2, which one was width at bottom and height? I'm just wondering what the general formula would be.

Comment: The general formula is $\frac{\text{bottom width} - \text{top width}}{\text{height}}$. But the sign changes depending on which direction you integrate in. In my solution above, I define the $h$-axis to point from the top to the bottom of the gate, which in turn means that the width of the gate decreases as you get deeper into the canal. This is why the slope for my linear function is negative.